# PDF download stalls in IE8

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-8, download

I have a problem that I'm completely stumped on how to diagnose and resolve. I have a website with a bunch of PDFs that should open in a new tab/window. However, the client is having trouble viewing the PDF in IE8 - they say that the download stops after a few hundred KB. The PDFs are not huge, less than 10MB.

The page in question is: http://familyfoods.ca/flyer-download/. Click on any of the store links to download a PDF. The PDF the client reported is fffAA-1.pdf (accessible from Bassano Family Foods, 1st link under Alberta).

Any help at all is seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered many times on stackoverflow, but your question gives the opportunity to post the answer that's come to my attention after 16 long hours of troubleshooting, guessing and Googling till my fingers hurt.

The problem is that IE8 was refusing to download PDF files or open them in the browser. The site in question is secure (SSL Encryption), and the files are being streamed out of location outside the web root using PHP.

Basically all the existing examples you'll see point out the various headers that you should send to the browser, and there are arguments about which are best and which ones do and do not work. There are links to Microsoft articles describing bugs affecting caching in Internet Explorer 5-8 and so forth that you'll see, but what I never saw was the following;

```
//Full working example code
session_cache_limiter('');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: private,post-check=0,pre-check=0,max-age=1');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"; modification-date="'.$modified.'"; size='.filesize($filename).';');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($filename);
```

**The Magic Answer: session_cache_limiter**

What isn't apparent is that session_cache_limiter(''); is needed when you're also using sessions, because it sends it's own caching headers and if you're not aware of this, or at least paying attention then it'll slip by you and IE8 (Internet Explorer 8.0) will refused to download streamed PDF files using headers like those above. By issuing the function with a zero-length string parameter which disables these caching headers sent by the session system, it allows you finally to control the headers going to IE and thereby avoid this "gotcha".